How to solve camera problem?
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04 on Acer Predator Helios Neo 16.
When i try to open any webcam software, as cheese, these no recognize my device. When I type this command: dmesg | grep uvc
return this:
[ 2.323488] uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to query (129) UVC probe control : 26 (exp. 48).
[ 2.323493] uvcvideo 1-6:1.1: Failed to initialize the device (-5).
[ 2.323539] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:4035 Quanta Computer, Inc. ACER HD User Facing
Device Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 1
bcdUSB 2.01
bDeviceClass 239 Miscellaneous Device
bDeviceSubClass 2 [unknown]
bDeviceProtocol 1 Interface Association
bMaxPacketSize0 64
idVendor 0x0408 Quanta Computer, Inc.
idProduct 0x4035 ACER HD User Facing
bcdDevice 0.04
iManufacturer 1 Quanta
iProduct 2 ACER HD User Facing
iSerial 3 01.00.00
bNumConfigurations 1
Configuration Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 2
wTotalLength 0x0255
bNumInterfaces 3
bConfigurationValue 1
iConfiguration 0
bmAttributes 0x80
(Bus Powered)
MaxPower 500mA
Interface Association:
bLength 8
bDescriptorType 11
bFirstInterface 0
bInterfaceCount 2
bFunctionClass 14 Video
bFunctionSubClass 3 Video Interface Collection
bFunctionProtocol 0
iFunction 4 ACER HD User Facing
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 0
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 1 Video Control
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 4 ACER HD User Facing
VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
bLength 13
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 1 (HEADER)
bcdUVC 1.50
wTotalLength 0x006f
dwClockFrequency 48.000000MHz
bInCollection 1
baInterfaceNr( 0) 1
VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
bLength 18
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 2 (INPUT_TERMINAL)
bTerminalID 1
wTerminalType 0x0201 Camera Sensor
bAssocTerminal 0
iTerminal 0
wObjectiveFocalLengthMin 0
wObjectiveFocalLengthMax 0
wOcularFocalLength 0
bControlSize 3
bmControls 0x0020000e
Auto-Exposure Mode
Auto-Exposure Priority
Exposure Time (Absolute)
Region of Interest
VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
bLength 13
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 5 (PROCESSING_UNIT)
bUnitID 2
bSourceID 1
wMaxMultiplier 16384
bControlSize 3
bmControls 0x0000157f
Brightness
Contrast
Hue
Saturation
Sharpness
Gamma
White Balance Temperature
Backlight Compensation
Power Line Frequency
White Balance Temperature, Auto
iProcessing 0
bmVideoStandards 0x00
VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
bLength 29
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
bUnitID 3
guidExtensionCode {26b8105a-0713-4870-979d-da79444bb68e}
bNumControls 1
bNrInPins 1
baSourceID( 0) 2
bControlSize 4
bmControls( 0) 0x04
bmControls( 1) 0x00
bmControls( 2) 0x00
bmControls( 3) 0x00
iExtension 0
VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
bLength 29
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 6 (EXTENSION_UNIT)
bUnitID 4
guidExtensionCode {63610682-5070-49ab-b8cc-b3855e8d221d}
bNumControls 26
bNrInPins 1
baSourceID( 0) 3
bControlSize 4
bmControls( 0) 0xff
bmControls( 1) 0xff
bmControls( 2) 0x77
bmControls( 3) 0x47
iExtension 0
VideoControl Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 3 (OUTPUT_TERMINAL)
bTerminalID 5
wTerminalType 0x0101 USB Streaming
bAssocTerminal 0
bSourceID 4
iTerminal 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x87 EP 7 IN
bmAttributes 3
Transfer Type Interrupt
Synch Type None
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0010 1x 16 bytes
bInterval 8
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 0
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 15
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 1 (INPUT_HEADER)
bNumFormats 2
wTotalLength 0x00f5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmInfo 0
bTerminalLink 5
bStillCaptureMethod 1
bTriggerSupport 0
bTriggerUsage 0
bControlSize 1
bmaControls( 0) 4
bmaControls( 1) 0
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 11
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 6 (FORMAT_MJPEG)
bFormatIndex 1
bNumFrameDescriptors 3
bFlags 1
Fixed-size samples: Yes
bDefaultFrameIndex 1
bAspectRatioX 0
bAspectRatioY 0
bmInterlaceFlags 0x00
Interlaced stream or variable: No
Fields per frame: 1 fields
Field 1 first: No
Field pattern: Field 1 only
bCopyProtect 0
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 30
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
bFrameIndex 1
bmCapabilities 0x01
Still image supported
wWidth 1280
wHeight 720
dwMinBitRate 442368000
dwMaxBitRate 442368000
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 1843200
dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333
bFrameIntervalType 1
dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 30
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
bFrameIndex 2
bmCapabilities 0x01
Still image supported
wWidth 640
wHeight 480
dwMinBitRate 147456000
dwMaxBitRate 147456000
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 614400
dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333
bFrameIntervalType 1
dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 30
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 7 (FRAME_MJPEG)
bFrameIndex 3
bmCapabilities 0x01
Still image supported
wWidth 640
wHeight 360
dwMinBitRate 110592000
dwMaxBitRate 110592000
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 460800
dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333
bFrameIntervalType 1
dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 6
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 13 (COLORFORMAT)
bColorPrimaries 1 (BT.709,sRGB)
bTransferCharacteristics 1 (BT.709)
bMatrixCoefficients 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 27
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 4 (FORMAT_UNCOMPRESSED)
bFormatIndex 2
bNumFrameDescriptors 3
guidFormat {32595559-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71}
bBitsPerPixel 16
bDefaultFrameIndex 1
bAspectRatioX 0
bAspectRatioY 0
bmInterlaceFlags 0x00
Interlaced stream or variable: No
Fields per frame: 2 fields
Field 1 first: No
Field pattern: Field 1 only
bCopyProtect 0
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 30
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
bFrameIndex 1
bmCapabilities 0x01
Still image supported
wWidth 1280
wHeight 720
dwMinBitRate 147456000
dwMaxBitRate 147456000
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 1843200
dwDefaultFrameInterval 1000000
bFrameIntervalType 1
dwFrameInterval( 0) 1000000
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 30
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
bFrameIndex 2
bmCapabilities 0x01
Still image supported
wWidth 640
wHeight 480
dwMinBitRate 147456000
dwMaxBitRate 147456000
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 614400
dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333
bFrameIntervalType 1
dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 30
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 5 (FRAME_UNCOMPRESSED)
bFrameIndex 3
bmCapabilities 0x01
Still image supported
wWidth 640
wHeight 360
dwMinBitRate 110592000
dwMaxBitRate 110592000
dwMaxVideoFrameBufferSize 460800
dwDefaultFrameInterval 333333
bFrameIntervalType 1
dwFrameInterval( 0) 333333
VideoStreaming Interface Descriptor:
bLength 6
bDescriptorType 36
bDescriptorSubtype 13 (COLORFORMAT)
bColorPrimaries 1 (BT.709,sRGB)
bTransferCharacteristics 1 (BT.709)
bMatrixCoefficients 4 (SMPTE 170M (BT.601))
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 1
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x00c0 1x 192 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 2
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0180 1x 384 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 3
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0200 1x 512 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 4
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0280 1x 640 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 5
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0320 1x 800 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 6
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x03b0 1x 944 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 7
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0a80 2x 640 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 8
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0b20 2x 800 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 9
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x0be0 2x 992 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 10
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x13c0 3x 960 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 1
bAlternateSetting 11
bNumEndpoints 1
bInterfaceClass 14 Video
bInterfaceSubClass 2 Video Streaming
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 0
Endpoint Descriptor:
bLength 7
bDescriptorType 5
bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
bmAttributes 5
Transfer Type Isochronous
Synch Type Asynchronous
Usage Type Data
wMaxPacketSize 0x13fc 3x 1020 bytes
bInterval 1
Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 4
bInterfaceNumber 2
bAlternateSetting 0
bNumEndpoints 0
bInterfaceClass 254 Application Specific Interface
bInterfaceSubClass 1 Device Firmware Update
bInterfaceProtocol 1
iInterface 12 APP Mode
Device Firmware Upgrade Interface Descriptor:
bLength 9
bDescriptorType 33
bmAttributes 15
Will Detach
Manifestation Tolerant
Upload Supported
Download Supported
wDetachTimeout 2000 milliseconds
wTransferSize 4096 bytes
bcdDFUVersion 1.10
Binary Object Store Descriptor:
bLength 5
bDescriptorType 15
wTotalLength 0x0029
bNumDeviceCaps 2
Platform Device Capability:
bLength 28
bDescriptorType 16
bDevCapabilityType 5
bReserved 0
PlatformCapabilityUUID {d8dd60df-4589-4cc7-9cd2-659d9e648a9f}
CapabilityData[0] 0x00
CapabilityData[1] 0x00
CapabilityData[2] 0x03
CapabilityData[3] 0x06
CapabilityData[4] 0x34
CapabilityData[5] 0x03
CapabilityData[6] 0x01
CapabilityData[7] 0x00
** UNRECOGNIZED: 08 10 11 01 03 00 00 00
Device Status: 0x0000
(Bus Powered)

Can any help me to resolve this problem. I need to fix-it to my work
Thanks
